# Difference between the Persian and Double harmonic scales

Tags: theory, scales

By looking at Wikipedia, both [Persian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_scale) and [Double harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale) scales seem pretty different.

However, I have a book about scales for guitar where I found this Persian scale which, to me, sounds exactly like the Double harmonic one:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They sound *nearly* exactly the same. There is a slight difference, in that the 5 of the Persian is a ♭5, whereas the 5 in the double hamonic is P5. Playing a melody which didn't have a 5 (quite rare!), it would be impossible to say which scale is being used out of the two.

The one posted has a P5, so can't be the Persian scale. And seems to go awry in its middle. Sometimes, there are inaccuracies on the net - particularly on, it seems, guitar sites...

Comment: To me the diagram seems correct for double harmonic scale, or do I miss something?

Comment: @user1079505 - I meant if it's supposed to be Persian, it goes awry.

Comment: So you agree the diagram from my book is double harmonic and not persian? I'll just write a note next to it in the book

Comment: If it's stated in a book, and it's wrong, at least the publishers have a right to know as well.